# SAML URL works in IE and Firefox, but not in Chrome of Safari

Tags: google-chrome, iis

I have a URL here:
www.soph.uab.edu/interntrackv3/saml_login

If you go to that URL with IE or Firefox, you will be redirected to my IdP for login.  If you go that site with Chrome or Safari, you will download a file that is an HTML file if you open it.

I need Chrome and Safari to redirect like IE and Firefox do.  This was working on IIS7.0 PHP 5.6.4.  I am now on IIS10 and PHP 7.3.  I'm assuming this is a server setting and some issue with the way Chrome and Safari handle the type of file being generated (this file is not stored anywhere on my server that I can find - it is generated at request time).

Anyone know what setting could have changed that would cause this change in behavior?  Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I’ve got it fixed.  When the site was redirected from HTTP to HTTPS it was changing the Header of the file from text/html to document under Google Chrome.  I added:

```
<httpProtocol>
    <customHeaders>
        <add name="X-Content-Type-Options" value="nosniff" />
    </customHeaders>
</httpProtocol>
```

To my `web.config` file and it is now working correctly.